# Setting background image for QPushButton

Tags: image, qt4, background

I am struggling to set an background image for an QPushButton. No Success till now. Following is my code.

```
appsWidget::appsWidget(QWidget *parent)
    :QWidget(parent)
{
    QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("SETTINGS",this);
    QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("TEST",this);
    QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("IE",this);

    button1->setStyleSheet("background-image:url(config.png)"); -> No success


    qDebug("appWidget initialized.");

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    layout->addWidget(button3);
    this->setLayout(layout);
    connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(setClickIndex1()));
    connect(button2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(setClickIndex2()));
    connect(button3,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(setClickIndex3()));
}
```

The image I am using in the stylesheet is located in the same project folder.
Do anybody has any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the flat attribute to true:

`button1->setFlat(true);`

You also have to set the autofillbackground -

`button1->setAutoFillBackground(true);`

You may want to look at QToolButton which doesn't require it to be flat in order to render an image. I'm using them in an app I'm writing at the moment and they look very nice:

```
m_showAddCommentButton = new QToolButton();
m_showAddCommentButton->setAutoFillBackground(true);
palette = m_showAddCommentButton->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Button,QColor(82,110,166));
m_showAddCommentButton->setPalette(palette);
m_showAddCommentButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/uiImages/addComment_50_50.jpg"));
m_showAddCommentButton->setIconSize(QSize(40,40));
m_showAddCommentButton->setToolTip("Comment");
connect(m_showAddCommentButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        manager, SLOT(showAddComment()));
hLayout->addWidget(m_showAddCommentButton,0);
```

(My image is stored as a resource)

Comment: In the above code should i resize my Image to fit to the button or it will be taken care of automatically?

Comment: You can go either way. Originally I resized my image to 50x50 externally in an editor, but then decided I wanted 40x40 - `setIconSize()` scales the icon to whatever you want.

Comment: This is not correct, you do not have to set the flat attribute or the auto fill background. You can simply load the image through `setIcon(":/path/to/image.png")`. I will usually first load the image in a `QPixmap` so it can be leveraged as a paint device and then pass in the Pixmap to whatever element needs it.

Answer (score 3):

Your css selector is not correct.

You should do something like:

```
button1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{ background-image: url(config.png); }");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use brush as palette element to fill background for any widget, for QPushButton that works when button is flat.

```
QPixmap pixmap("image.jpg");
QPalette palette;    
QPushButton *button= new QPushButton(this);
palette.setBrush(button->backgroundRole(), QBrush(pixmap));

button->setFlat(true);
button->setAutoFillBackground(true);    
button->setPalette(palette);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody needs a solution for this in Python, because I was not able to find anything here:

```
    label = QLabel(self)
    label.setGeometry(self.butt_top_left.geometry())
    pixmap = QPixmap('path_to_your_symbol/symbol.png')
    pixmap = pixmap.scaled(label.size(), Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio)
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    label.show()
```

Here you are creating a label that position is exactly on your button. This was working out for me.