# how to create a custom button pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

Is it possible to do this with a qpushbutton? The images and labels can be change dynamically through code. Do i need to create a custom widget for this?
thanks.

[image]

Comment: you want the pushbutton to look like the whole schematic or what? also, do you mean if you have to override the paint method by “Do i need to create a custom widget for this?” the answer for the latter would be no. also, why do you want a button to look like this?

Comment: yea i want it look like that as a whole if possible. Can this be done by overriding paint method? if not, is there other way to achieve this? its ok if its not a button.

Comment: what are the images in the corners for, what the one in the background?

Comment: the whole background is like a widget/frame with an image background, the 4 images and 2 labels are nested in that widget/frame.

Comment: get started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671842/setting-background-image-for-qpushbutton).