# Qt Background Image for a QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, background-image, qpixmap, qpushbutton

I need to put an image from the internal resources as a background image of a QPushButton. I need also to adapt the size of the image to the size of the button.
I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671842/setting-background-image-for-qpushbutton/2671981) some way to do that, but nothing seems to work.
In the last reply it was suggested the use of the following code:

```
QPixmap pixmap("image.jpg");
QPalette palette;    
QPushButton *button= new QPushButton(this);
palette.setBrush(button->backgroundRole(), QBrush(pixmap));
button->setFlat(true);
button->setAutoFillBackground(true);    
button->setPalette(palette);
```

So I took that code and changed it a bit 'cause I'm using a ui made with QTCreator:

```
void MyDialog::SetBgImage(QWidget *pButton)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(":/Icons/images/Sfondo.png");
    QPalette palette = pButton->palette();
    palette.setBrush(pButton->backgroundRole(), QBrush(pixmap)); // 1
    QPushButton *pPButton = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(pButton);
    if (pPButton!=NULL)
           pPButton->setFlat(true);
    pButton->setAutoFillBackground(true);
   pButton->setPalette(palette); // 2
```

}

In the constructor I call it in this way:

```
SetBgImage(ui->pushButton_Button1);
```

when the dialog is showed the button is displayed correctly. Unfortunately when I close the dialog I get the following error message:

> *** glibc detected *** ./MyAppName: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0047dc78 ***

If I remove the line marked with **//1** or the line marked with **//2** the error disappear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
button->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/Icons/images/Sfondo.png);");
```

Or change stylesheet from designer.

Answer (score 0):

ui->pushButton_5->setStyleSheet("backgroundimage:url(/home/Desktop/qtproject/
sample2/images
/11.png);");

For Setting background in Qpushbutton

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it worked for me :
ui->pushButton_2->setStyleSheet("background-image:url(C://Users//XXXX//Desktop//menu//icon.png);");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).