# Qt PushButton icon appears left to the actual button, how do I center or stretch it?

Tags: c++, qt

when I add an icon to my button, it appears left to my text and if I shrink the button size, part of the icon actually remains outside of the button. I want the icon to be the button, as in - to be the entire texture of the button. How can i center it, or is the icon not what I'm looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting background image for QPushButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671842/setting-background-image-for-qpushbutton)

Comment: If you just want an icon, remove the text by setting it to "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to use CSS instead the `setIcon` method. But anyway, you should get the right behaviour with the next code:

```
QPushbutton *button = new QPushbutton;
QPixmap pixmap("path_to_image");
QIcon ButtonIcon(pixmap);
button->setIcon(ButtonIcon);
button->setIconSize(pixmap.rect().size());
```

As I said before, you can get a very good solution applying styles:

```
button->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/path/to/image);");
```

I have a [repo](https://github.com/ftena/qt-snippets) in GitHub where you can play with different stylesheets. In fact, there are three qss which are using the `background-image` property.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [stylesheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) for this.

For the image to take all the available space :

```
QPushButton
{
     border-image: url(":/your_image");
}
```

For the image to be in the center with a constant size :

```
QPushButton
{
    background-image: url(":/your_image") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: I suppose @ulak-blade wants to change only a certain button, so it's preferable to use something like `QPushButton#your_button`

Comment: You're right but it depends on which widget he applies the stylesheet to. I was thinking about the simplest way : changing the stylesheet of this particular button from QtDesigner.